# Male and female budgies fighting

Tags: birds

Hello I have male and a female budgie and they keep fighting. They don't really stop. They are a couple and I don't want to split them.I have a sheet over their cage and they have kinda stopped and still fight alittle under the sheet. How can I make them stop fighting?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but those who can will want to know how long the two have been together in the same cage.  As well as how long the fighting has been going on, and what happened before it started.

Answer (score 2):

Need to separate, not all male/female of same species will get along. You cannot train them to want to be together.
If they are constantly fighting they are not a bonded pair.
Introducing one bird to the other needs time and an extra cage on hand.

When acquiring a new bird:

1) Ideally there should be a 3-6 month quarantine to prevent spread of infectious diseases if they have some, during this time frame you will see if your new bird develops any illness.

2) Once quarantine is done place bird #2 in the same room (but not the same cage) as your original.

3) After a week you can place bird #2's cage next to bird #1 for them to get a better look at each other and to get more familiar.

4) After another week you may try introducing them to each other outside and away from their cages. (Some birds can be cage aggressive/possessive).

5) After multiple play sessions outside of their cages goes well and you feel confident that they get along you may place them on the same cage. Watch their reactions/body language if you feel that they love each other you will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If the cage is too small, they might be having territorial issues. Budgies are not usually a type of bird where gender matters. I have my six with all mixed genders, some male, some female. Maybe try getting a bigger cage or something for them each to do when they are bored?